# dependent select in react js

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

i have 2 select elements
first one is:

```
<select>
   <option>1</option>
   <option>2</option>
   <option>3</option>
</select>
```

Second one is:

```
<select>
   <option>1.1</option>
   <option>1.2</option>
   <option>1.3</option>
   <option>1.4</option>
   <option>2.1</option>
   <option>2.2</option>
   <option>2.3</option>
   <option>2.4</option>
   <option>2.5</option>
</select>
```

Second one will be hidden by default. when I select an option from first one and if that option got any sub item in second one then second one will show and only the options that are related to the first one selected option will be visible in second select element.

More details:
I selected 1 from first select element. then second select element will show and second select element will show only options that are related to 1, like, only 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4 options will be visible for second select option.

And if I select 3 from first select option then second select element will be hidden coz second select element got no items that are related to 3.

that's all. How can I achieve this using react hooks.

Comment: https://roytuts.com/cascading-or-dependent-dropdown-using-react-js/

This will help

Comment: thanks @FahimHoque . but vi do not need for country, state. i need a simple solution. please read my issue. this is different. i mean bit different then country, state issue. anw, Thanks a lot for your kind response.

Comment: The link I provided is just a sample. Study it and try to implement the idea on your own

Comment: Please don't include notes like "thanks in advanced[sic]" in questions. See [no thanks](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288160/no-thanks-damn-it).

Comment: What have you tried? I don't see any code samples.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `useState` in order to create a component variable.

```
[firstSelectAnswer, setFirstSelectAnswer] = useState('1');
```

This variable will hold the selected value from the first select box, for example by default 1; We will bind on change event on select or on click event on option in order to receive newly selected value.

```
firstSelectOptions = ["1", "2", "3"]
...
<select onChange={(e) => {setFirstSelectAnswer(e.target.value)}} value={firstSelectAnswer}>
   {
      firstSelectOptions.map((option) => <option key={option} value={option}>{option}</option>)
   }
</select>
```

We can use `secondSelectAnswer` variable in order to hold the answer from the second select box.

```
[secondSelectAnswer, setSecondSelectAnswer] = useState();
secondSelectOptions = [
   {key: "1", value: "1.1"},
   {key: "1", value: "1.2"},
   {key: "1", value: "1.3"},
   {key: "1", value: "1.4"},
   {key: "2", value: "2.1"},
   {key: "2", value: "2.2"},
   {key: "2", value: "2.3"},
   {key: "2", value: "2.4"},
   {key: "2", value: "2.5"}
]
...
```

We can use conditional rendering in order to show only required options:

```
{
   (firstSelectAnswer == '1' || firstSelectAnswer == '2') &&  
      <select onChange={(e) => {setSecondSelectAnswer(e.target.value)}} value={secondSelectAnswer}>
        {
           secondSelectOptions
             .filter(option => {return option.required == firstSelectAnswer})
             .map((option) => 
                <option 
                   key={option.value} 
                   value={option.value}>
                 {option.value}
                </option>)
        }
      </select>
}
```

Variables `firsSelectAnswer` and `secondSelectAnswer` will hold appropriate values.